# How do I migrate a database between servers from SQL 2008 Std to SQL 2014 Std using T-SQL without losing data?

Tags: sql-server, database

What is the process using T-SQL to copy/move/relocate a database from one server to another?  Do I need to take a log backup on the source as well and restore it on the new server?

I am pretty sure that when I originally moved them to the current server, I only had to perform a full backup, but when I just tried that, I was definitely missing data.

The source server is SQL 2008 Standard and the destination server is SQL 2014 Standard.

The database names and filepaths are identical between servers.

Are there any additional considerations after I perform the migration?

Comment: Did the users create or update data in the source database after the backup? If so, then I'd expect there to be missing/different data in the restored database. If you need the data to be consistent then don't allow any additional updates/creates/etc. on the source database after the backup. A Full backup is sufficient, hence the name `Full`.

Comment: The server hosting the application was shutdown and no other apps/users were updating the database.

Comment: How did you determine that data was missing? I'm failing to see how a Full database backup would be missing data. That would be a pretty big flaw and we'd have undoubtedly heard about it.

Comment: I looked at the max id of the main table in each instance.  I did the backup / restore process 2-3 times with same result.  This is the TSQL I used for the backup (after shutting down the apps)  

BACKUP DATABASE dbName
TO Disk = '\\sql2014zoned\_Import\dbName-Migration-Full.Bak'
WITH COMPRESSION, COPY_ONLY
GO

Comment: And how are you going about finding the max id? Does your query properly sort on the id field?

Comment: Also, a log backup will not follow the chain of your current backup. The `COPY_ONLY` switch means your backup is separate from the current backup chain.

Comment: So.. just to verify.  The backup TSQL I posted above should be sufficient to do a full backup of all data on the source server?

Comment: Can you post the query you used to compare the max IDs? Also, are the row counts of your main table different too?

Comment: @TTT - Select ID From Table Order By ID desc